# Comparing NSArray with keys with a NSString

Tags: ios

I am downloading JSON objects and passing them to a `NSMutableArray`. On another view controller, I received the `NSMutableArray` converted to a `NSArray`.

Here is the code in the view controller where I get the `NSArray` items received from JSON:

```
-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _feedItems = items;

  //I need to iterate items and compare name value from each
  //from each item with a string 


}
```

The array has four keys: name, latitude, longitude, state.

What I need is to compare all the array objects name value with a NSString.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. Keys are in dictionaries.

Comment: Have you read the docs for `NSArray`? This is a method to see if it has a given object in it.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for your comment, but in this tutorial: http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/ the author is getting a NSArray with keys, at least that's what I understand from the text, the NSArray is used to feed a tableview.

Comment: I'm not going through that rather long tutorial. Perhaps you have an array of dictionaries or an array of some custom object.

Comment: The author is getting an array of dictionaries (which have the keys) which he converts to an array of custom objects.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy, you must be right, I will try to learn from it and get a better solution.

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar  , I will try to learn from it and get a better solution.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have found a solution to my problem, I have posted an answer. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @rdelmar , I have found a solution to my problem, I have posted an answer. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

rmaddy and rdelmar are right, it is an array of custom objects. I have solved my problem as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= _feedItems.count-1; i++) {
        Location *item = [_feedItems objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *nombreactual = item.name;
        NSLog(@"Lugar=%@", nombreactual);
       }
```

Now I can easily compare the value from item.name with the string  I need.

Thank you both.

Comment: Use modern syntax. Replace the 1st two lines with this one: `for (Location *item in _feedItems) {`.

Comment: If you want to use your `for` loop (which is fine), you do need to fix two things. Change it to: `for (NSInteger i = 0; i < _feedItems.count; i++) {`. Note that you shouldn't use `int` and be really careful using `someArray.count - 1`. If the array is empty, this will give you a huge number, not -1 since `NSArray count` is an unsigned integer (`NSUInteger`).

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you again. I am an old man, and it is never too late to learn. I have implemented your modern version, it works. :)

Comment: Based on your username, I'm older than you (barely). :)

Comment: @rmaddy, it has been a very productive evening, I have learned a lot from your comments.